# how to cluster trajectories of x,y coordinates in r?

Tags: python, r, dbscan

i'm trying to clustering trajectories. But this is not easy. 
   The following stream data (spatio-temporal data) exists.

[image]

Here, we can see that each Object_ID has several x, y, and this is a 
   trajectory.
   So I want to follow these points and get the following clusters:

[image]

I have already thought of many ways. For example, DBSCAN, TRACLUS, ...
But if I use DBSCAN, I do not know how to put the input value.
In other words, how do I put each object_ID line as an input value? (What 
form?)
Or is there a way to put multiple coordinates of each Object_ID first?

```
object_1: [{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {y3, y3}, ... {xn, yn}],
object_2: [{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {y3, y3}, ... {xn, yn}],
object_3: [{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {y3, y3}, ... {xn, yn}],
.
.
.
```

And after I get cluster results, each cluster must have Object information.

Do you know anyone in r or python?

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN has no particular requirements on the data type.

You just need to be able to compute distances.

So organize the data as necessary for your time series distance function.

Is then try HAC first, then DBSCAN.

Comment: If so, is k-means the same as DBSCAN?
I don't know how to put the input value when I run k-means in r.

Comment: In general, the input data of k-means and DBSCAN examples consist of points. So it is difficult to approach.

Comment: No, k-means computes means. It needs coordinates, and it cannot use arbitrary distances. Worst choice here. DBSCAN does not require coordinates (a bad implementation may). It can be implemented on polygons, timeseries, audio, ... anything where you have a distance function (or similarity, or any other neighbor predicate).